# Function with DIV Toggle Specification

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'd like to have a a div show only when one button is clicked and also have it close when the other button is clicked. I have the code below but when I added it to m y page, everything disappeared except for the buttons. How do I get it toddle just a particular DIV.

```
<style>
  div { background:#def3ca; margin:3px; width:80px; 
  display:none; float:left; text-align:center; }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <button id="showr">Show</button>
  <button id="hidr">Hide</button>
  <div>Hello 3,</div>

  <div>how</div>
  <div>are</div>
  <div>you?</div>
<script>
$("#showr").click(function () {
  $("div:eq(0)").show("fast", function () {
    /* use callee so don't have to name the function */
    $(this).next("div").show("fast", arguments.callee);
  });
});
$("#hidr").click(function () {
  $("div").hide(2000);
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason everything disappears is because you told it to! In your CSS, you have the rule for all `div`s to be `display: none;` (invisible).

Instead, you want only the div you are trying to hide initially to have an *inline style* of `display: none;`.

i.e. change your CSS to:

```
<style>
  div { background:#def3ca; margin:3px; width:80px; 
  float:left; text-align:center; }
  </style>
```

and your divs to:

```
  <div style="display: none;">Hello 3,</div>

  <div>how</div>
  <div>are</div>
  <div>you?</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you are showing again in your callback function on #showr and in your #hidr click you are just hiding all divs.  Take a look at this fiddle that appears to do what you need:

http://jsfiddle.net/VdUdE/

Basically I am just selecting the first/last hidden/visible element based on which button you click and showing/hiding it. Code:

```
$("#showr").click(function () {
    $(this).siblings("div:hidden:first").show("fast");

});
$("#hidr").click(function () {
    $(this).siblings("div:visible:last").hide("fast");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I this you are looking for ?

```
<style>
  div { background:#def3ca; margin:3px; width:80px; 
  display:none; float:left; text-align:center; }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <button id="showr">Show</button>
  <button id="hidr">Hide</button>
  <div id="1">Hello 3,</div>

  <div id="2">how</div>
  <div id="3">are</div>
  <div id="4">you?</div>
<script>
    var Counter = 0;
$("#showr").click(function () {
    Counter = Counter + 1;
    if(Counter > 4){ Counter = 4;}
  $('#'+Counter).show("fast", function () {

  });

});
$("#hidr").click(function () {
  $("#"+Counter).hide(2000);
     If(Counter > 0 ) 
         Counter = Counter -1;

});

</script>
```

test link
http://jsfiddle.net/fPfvg/

Comment: IDs cannot start with a number in HTML

Comment: That is true.  Still probably not a good idea to get into the habit of writing invalid HTML to get your jQuery working.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Chico State Grad?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4852/discussion-between-abe-miessler-and-tmjam)